# JQuery: Change width on window resize always becomes 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the width of a `div` element on window resize but due to the resize function the width of the element is always 0 in the end

```
   function resizeUploadField() {
        var uploadInputField = $('.input-append');
        var uploadSelectButton = $('.btn-file');
        var uploadRemoveButton = $('.fileupload-exists');

        if (uploadRemoveButton.length) {

        }
        console.log(uploadInputField.width());
        uploadInputField.width(uploadInputField.width() - uploadSelectButton.outerWidth() - 2);
        console.log(uploadInputField.width());
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        resizeUploadField();

        $(window).resize(function(event) {
            console.log($(event.target).width());
            if ($(event.target).width() != windowWidth) {
                resizeUploadField();
                windowWidth =  $(event.target).width();
            }

        });
```

The `resizeUploadField` function seems to work properly since the field is properly resized when called in onDocumentReady

Maybe someone can give me a hint what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to redeclare the `windowWidth = $(window).width();` inside the `resize()` function.

**E.g.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    resizeUploadField();

    $(window).resize(function(event) {
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log($(event.target).width());
        if ($(event.target).width() != windowWidth) {
            resizeUploadField();
            windowWidth = $(event.target).width();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is just ignoring the if statement because $(event.target).width() != windowWidth is never true

Comment: @Nickolaus I forgot. You are resizing the same `window` or `element`. What's the main goal?

Comment: I want to change the width of an element if the window is resized horizontally

Comment: @Nickolaus Then you can just use css.

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible because the HTML is nested into a display table with fixed table-layout in order display the content properly